# Using mscomm ActiveX with Qt

Tags: qt, activex, mscomm32

I know this question may seem odd due to new existing alternatives, but trust me there's a reason.

I would like to use the mscomm active X control to communicate through serial port with Qt.
Yes, I know there's QextSerialPort, QSerialDevice and a lot of examples about how to write serial communication code. But due a problems I have I would like to test mscomm.

I know Qt has a system to use ActiveX controls, but I cannot find any clear information about how to use them (I don't understand the qt official doc about this).

Visual C++ 6 has a mscomm.h and mscomm.cpp which I think implements the active x interface, but is plenty of microsoft mfc macros and dependencies everywhere.

Any clue?

Comment: You should post the answer to the problem as an answer instead of editing it into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, seems I achieved it.

You must use QAxObject to wrap the activeX you want to execute. To do so you need to know the CLSID, in my case :

```
  QAxObject* activex = new QAxObject("648A5600-2C6E-101B-82B6-000000000014");
```

Then you only need to use dynamicCall( QString, QVariant ) to call any of the members the ActiveX control has. To generate a list of all available methods use:

```
  QString doc = activex->generateDocumentation();
```

This is wonderful, you get an html document with all available members, properties and examples which explain how to use them (Qt Documentation tell you can use *dumpdoc* to generate the same info)

Here an example on how to open a port (port number 4):

```
  QAxObject* activex = new QAxObject("648A5600-2C6E-101B-82B6-000000000014");
  activex->dynamicCall("SetCommPort(int)", 4);
  activex->dynamicCall("SetPortOpen(bool)", true);
```